# query no guarda registros a la bd

Tags: php, html5

Bueno lo que pasa es que estoy haciendo un formulario pero no me estan guardando los registros en la base de datos no se a que se deba esta es la tabla

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>

<body>

<marquee bgcolor="#0000CC"> INGRESE SUS DATOS</marquee>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="Datospersonales.php">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p><strong>DATOS PERSONALES </strong>  </p>
  <table width="353" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td>ID</td>
      <td><label for="id"></label>
      <input type="text" name="id" id="id" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NOMBRE</td>
      <td><label for="nombres"></label>
      <input type="text" name="nombres" id="nombres" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>PATERNO</td>
      <td><label for="paterno"></label>
      <input type="text" name="paterno" id="paterno" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>MATERNO</td>
      <td><label for="materno"></label>
      <input type="text" name="materno" id="materno" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ID CIIVIL</td>
      <td><label for="id_civil"></label>
      <input type="text" name="id_civil" id="id_civil" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DIRECCION</td>
      <td><label for="direccion"></label>
      <input type="text" name="direccion" id="direccion" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>EMAIL PRINCIPAL</td>
      <td><label for="correop"></label>
      <input type="text" name="correop" id="correop" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>EMAIL ALT.</td>
      <td><label for="correoa"></label>
      <input type="text" name="correoa" id="correoa" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CELULAR      </td>
      <td><label for="tcelular"></label>
      <input type="text" name="tcelular" id="tcelular" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>TELEFONO CASA</td>
      <td><label for="tcasa"></label>
      <input type="text" name="tcasa" id="tcasa" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>TELEFONO TRABAJO</td>
      <td><label for="ttrabajo"></label>
      <input type="text" name="ttrabajo" id="ttrabajo" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>F.NACIMIENTO</td>
      <td><input type="date" name="f_nacimiento" id="f_nacimiento" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>GENERO</td>
      <td><label for="genero"></label>
        <select name="genero" id="genero">
          <option value="1">Hombre</option>
          <option value="2">Mujer</option>
      </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>PAIS </td>
      <td><select name="pais_nacimiento" id="pais_nacimiento">
        <option>Alemania</option>
        <option>Argentina</option>
        <option>Autralia</option>
        <option>Bahamas</option>
        <option>Belgica</option>
        <option>Belice</option>
        <option>Bolivia</option>
        <option>Brasil</option>
        <option>Camerun</option>
        <option>Canada</option>
        <option>Chile</option>
        <option>China</option>
        <option>Ciudad del vaticano</option>
        <option>Colombia</option>
        <option>Corea del norte</option>
        <option>Corea del sur</option>
        <option>Costa rica</option>
        <option>Croacia</option>
        <option>Cuba</option>
        <option>Dinamarca</option>
        <option>Ecuador</option>
        <option>Egipto</option>
        <option>El salvador</option>
        <option>Eslovaquia</option>
        <option>España</option>
        <option>Estados Unidos</option>
        <option>Filipinas</option>
        <option>Francia</option>
        <option>Grecia</option>
        <option>Guatemala</option>
        <option>Honduras</option>
        <option>India</option>
        <option>Irak</option>
        <option>Iran</option>
        <option>Irlanda</option>
        <option>Jamaica</option>
        <option>Madagascar</option>
        <option>Montenegro</option>
        <option>Mexico</option>
        <option>Nueva Zelanda</option>
        <option>Peru</option>
        <option>Uruguay</option>
      </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ESTADO</td>
      <td><select name="edo_nacimiento" id="edo_nacimiento">
        <option>Aguascalientes</option>
        <option>Baja California</option>
      </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NACIONALIDAD</td>
      <td><select name="nacionalidad" id="nacionalidad">
        <option>mexicano</option>
      </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>IDENTIDAD</td>
      <td><select name="identidad" id="identidad">
        <option value="1">CURP</option>
        <option value="2">INE</option>
        <option value="3">IMSS</option>
        <option value="4">ISSSTE</option>
        <option value="5">ISSSTECALLI</option>
        <option value="6">CARTILLA</option>
      </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>FOTO</td>
      <td><label for="foto"></label>
      <input type="text" name="foto" id="foto" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="Enviar" id="Enviar" value="Enviar" />
  </p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</form>

<body background="file:///C:/Users/Desktop/carpetas%20de%20cosas/desarrollo/conacyt2.png">


</body>
</html>

este seria el php con los post estan iguales a la base de datos todo los id 
<?php 
include("conexion4.php");   
  if($_POST){  
$id=$_POST['id'];
$nombres=$_POST['nombres'];
$paterno=$_POST['paterno'];
$materno=$_POST['materno'];
$id_civil=$_POST['id_civil'];
$direccion=$_POST['direccion'];
$correop=$_POST['correop'];
$correoa=$_POST['correoa'];
$tcelular=$_POST['tcelular'];
$tcasa=$_POST['tcasa'];
$ttrabajo=$_POST['ttrabajo'];
$f_nacimiento=$_POST['f_nacimiento'];
$genero=$_POST['genero'];
$pais_nacimiento=$_POST['pais_nacimiento'];
$edo_nacimiento=$_POST['edo_nacimiento'];
$nacionalidad=$_POST['nacionalidad'];
$identidad=$_POST['identidad'];
$foto=$_POST['foto'];

}

$query="insert into tb_personales(id,nombres,paterno,materno,id_civil,direccion,correop,correoa,tcelular,tcasa,ttrabajo,f_nacimiento,genero,pais_nacimiento,edo_nacimiento,nacionalidad,identidad,foto) values('$id','$nombres','$paterno','$materno','$id_civil','$direccion','$correop','$correoa','$tcelular','$tcasa','$ttrabajo','$f_nacimiento','$genero','$pais_nacimiento','$edo_nacimiento', '$nacionalidad','$identidad','$foto')";

mysqli_db_query("bd_conacyt",$query);
```

con este conecto a la bd

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die (mysqli_error());
$db=mysqli_connect("bd_conacyt",$con) or die (mysqli_error());   

/**
 * @author www.intercambiosvirtuales.org
 * @copyright 2016
 */


?>
```

No sé que cuál sea el problema por que los campos estan igual hecho difrentes tipos de querys y no me guarda. Saludos

Comment: El enviar del if de donde lo sacas

Answer (score 1):

Tres cosas:
1.- Revisa tu archivo de mysql_error.log, en el podras tener mas detalle del error. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-logs.html

2.- Trata de imprimir algunas de las variables para asegurar que si estan obteniendo contenido del POST, solo para verificar.

3.- Prueba tu Query directo en tu manejador de base de datos, solo con datos de pruebas para ver si esta todo correcto con tu motor de base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el error está en `if(Enviar=="Enviar")` el primer enviar `php` asume que es una constantes no definida, ese enviar tiene que ser una variable donde debes asignar el valor del butón summit, usa `echo` y `die` para que hagas un debug simple y veas donde, puedes usar un debuger para php xdebug es una alternativa.

Answer (score 0):

Crea una variable llamada query y allí almacenas tu insert, luego lo sustituyes así:

```
 mysql_db_query("conacyt",$query);
```

Es mejor legible y además es para que hagas un echo de tu query, lo copies y ejecutes ese sql en tu administrador de bases de datos (comúnmente phpmyadmin), eligiendo tu DB, luego en la pestaña sql.

Allí sabrás si es tu query la que causa el error.

Otra cosa es esto:

```
if(Enviar=="Enviar")
```

¿De dónde sacas Enviar? ¿Es una constante? ¿O más bien es $_POST['Enviar']?

También revisa tu action del formulario:

```
action="Datospersonales.php"
```

Si estás apuntando al lugar indicado, que parece ser la misma página.

Esas dos pueden ser las causas.

**Nota:** es un código muy obsoleto, desde el usar tablas hasta la extensión mysql, quizá consideres renovarlo porque tarde que temprano dejará de funcionar correctamente.

Comment: El enviar es el nombre del boton del html lo raro es que hay unas tablas que si funcionan asi y otras no

Comment: $query="insert into tb_personales (id,nombres,paterno,materno,id_civil,direccion,correop,correoa,tcelular,tcasa,ttrabajo,f_nacimiento,genero,pais_nacimiento,
  edo_nacimiento,nacionalidad,identidad,foto) values('$id','$nombres','$paterno','$materno','$id_civil','$direccion','$correop','$correoa','$tcelular','$tcasa','$ttrabajo','$f_nacimiento','$genero','$pais_nacimiento','$edo_nacimiento',
  '$nacionalidad','$identidad','$foto')";
  
  
  mysqli_db_query("bd_conacyt",$query);

Comment: Debes repasar sql porque en el insert, en values, estás colocando '$id' pero $id es un entero, no una cadena. Es diferente 1 que '1'. Primero haz un insert en phpmyadmin o en lo que sea que uses, con puro sql, luego copias ese query y sustituyes los valores.

Answer (score 0):

Veo varios fallos en tu código:

- Intentas comparar `Enviar` en tu `if` y sin embargo no tienes definida esa variable (que además tendría que ir con un `$` delante). Imagino que lo que querrás hacer será `if($_POST["Enviar"] == "Enviar"){`
- En tu conexión utilizas una base de datos llamada `bd_conacyt` y en tu función `mysql_db_query` utilizas una llamada `conacyt`.

Por último, **no utilices las funciones `mysql` de PHP y utiliza las funciones de `mysqli` en su defecto** ya que con las primeras se ha demostrado que hay fallos de seguridad.

Comment: Yo no tengo problemas con las comillas dobles o simples, independientemente el tipo de dato (O al menos eso creo, solo lo he hecho con strings y numeros), ¿Eso depende por la versión de PHP que utilizo? @Error404

Comment: @Hoose Mira esta pregunta: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php. La verdad que desconozco si puede ser por la versión de PHP.

Comment: Si quitas las comillas simple se pasa como integer si pones comillas simple lo pasas como string... no tienes que concatenarlo como dices - [types.string](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php)

Comment: @aldanux Como la mejor forma de estar seguro es comprobándolo ahí que estaba creando un ejemplo básico. Tienes razón, se evalúan dentro. Pensaba que si introducías comillas simples dentro de dobles tomaban más preferencia las simples. Acabo de comprobar que solamente no se evalúan cuando englobas el String completo con comillas simples. Gracias por la corrección, ahora mismo modifico la respuesta.